# wso2 carbon-apimgt v.5.0.3 build error

Tags: git, maven, wso2, wso2-api-manager

i'm trying to make a modification to wso2 api management 1.10.0. From what i see in the pom.xml of wso2 api management product distribution source code, the carbon apimgt used is version v5.0.3

so i tried cloning carbon-apimgt from https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt.git and check out the v5.0.3. I succesfully did that and tried to build it by running

> mvn -X clean install

, but i got the following build error

```
[ERROR] Error building bundle org.wso2.carbon.apimgt:org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.core:bundle:5.0.3 : Unresolved references to [org.wso2.carbon.utils.multitenancy] by class(es) on the Bundle-Classpath[Jar:dot]: [org/wso2/carbon/apimgt/core/usage/APIStatsPublisher.class]
[ERROR] Error(s) found in bundle configuration
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] WSO2 Carbon - API Management Aggregator Pom ....... SUCCESS [0.933s]
[INFO] API Management .................................... SUCCESS [0.053s]
[INFO] WSO2 Carbon - API Security Handler Service Stub ... SUCCESS [8.057s]
[INFO] WSO2 Carbon - API Key Management Stub ............. SUCCESS [9.292s]
[INFO] WSO2 Carbon - API Gateway Management Stub ......... SUCCESS [4.587s]
[INFO] WSO2 Carbon - API Stat Publishing Status Update Service Stub  SUCCESS [3.130s]
[INFO] WSO2 Carbon - Tier Cache Service Stub ............. SUCCESS [2.519s]
[INFO] WSO2 Carbon - Registry Cache Invalidation Service Stub  SUCCESS [2.650s]
[INFO] OpenID Connect Authenticator stubs ................ SUCCESS [0.035s]
[INFO] WSO2 Carbon - OpenID Connect Authenticator Stub ... SUCCESS [5.345s]
[INFO] API Management .................................... SUCCESS [0.032s]
[INFO] WSO2 Carbon - Api for API Management .............. SUCCESS [2.005s]
[INFO] WSO2 Carbon - API Key Mgt Client .................. SUCCESS [2.632s]
[INFO] WSO2 Carbon - API Management Implementation ....... SUCCESS [48.436s]
[INFO] WSO2 Carbon - API Gateway ......................... SUCCESS [18.161s]
[INFO] WSO2 Carbon - API Management Usage Aggregator Module  SUCCESS [0.073s]
[INFO] WSO2 Carbon - API Management Usage Publisher ...... SUCCESS [8.843s]
[INFO] WSO2 Carbon - API Management Usage Client ......... SUCCESS [7.613s]
[INFO] WSO2 Carbon - HostObject for API management ....... SUCCESS [7.780s]
[INFO] WSO2 Carbon - API Key Mgt ......................... SUCCESS [4.501s]
[INFO] WSO2 Carbon - API Management Core ................. FAILURE [3.857s]
[INFO] WSO2 Carbon - API Management Interceptor .......... SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 Carbon - API Management Startup Publisher .... SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 Carbon - API Manager Rest API Utility ........ SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager Store REST API ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager Publisher REST API ............... SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 Carbon API Manager- Dynamic Client Registration Web Service  SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 Carbon - Sample API .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Forum ............................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 Carbon - Forum Component ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 Carbon - Hostobjects Aggregator Module ....... SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 Carbon - Single Sign-On Relying party HostObject  SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 Carbon - OIDC Based SSO Authenticator Aggregator Module  SKIPPED
[INFO] OIDC SSO Authenticator - UI bundle ................ SKIPPED
[INFO] OIDC Authenticator - BE bundle .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 Carbon -OIDC HostObject ...................... SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 Carbon - API management Feature Aggregator Module  SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 Carbon - Api management Core Feature ......... SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 Carbon - Api management Gateway Feature ...... SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 Carbon - API Publisher Feature ............... SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 Carbon - API Store Feature ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 Carbon - Api management Server Interceptor Feature  SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 Carbon - Api management Server Startup Publisher Feature  SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 Carbon - Api management Feature .............. SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 Carbon - Api management Key Manager Feature .. SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 Carbon - API Publisher Rest API Feature ...... SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 Carbon - API Store Rest API Feature .......... SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 Carbon - API Dynamic Client Registration Rest API Feature  SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 Carbon - Forum Feature Aggregator Module ..... SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 Carbon - Forum Server Feature ................ SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 Carbon - Forum Feature ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 Carbon - OIDC Authenticator Feature Aggregator Module  SKIPPED
[INFO] OIDC based authenticator UI Feature ............... SKIPPED
[INFO] OIDC based authenticator Server Feature ........... SKIPPED
[INFO] OIDC based Single Sign-On authenticator Feature ... SKIPPED
[INFO] OIDC based authenticator - Hostobject ............. SKIPPED
[INFO] WSO2 APIManager - Nested Feature Categories ....... SKIPPED
[INFO] API Gateway Manager 5.0.3 ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] API Gateway Worker 5.0.3 .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] API Key Manager 5.0.3 ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] API Publisher 5.0.3 ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] API Store 5.0.3 ................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2:22.222s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Feb 05 15:30:39 WIB 2016
[INFO] Final Memory: 249M/1020M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:1.4.0:bundle (default-bundle) on project org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.core: Error(s) found in bundle configuration -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:1.4.0:bundle (default-bundle) on project org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.core: Error(s) found in bundle configuration
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Error(s) found in bundle configuration
    at org.apache.felix.bundleplugin.BundlePlugin.execute(BundlePlugin.java:340)
    at org.apache.felix.bundleplugin.BundlePlugin.execute(BundlePlugin.java:226)
    at org.apache.felix.bundleplugin.BundlePlugin.execute(BundlePlugin.java:217)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: Error(s) found in bundle configuration
    at org.apache.felix.bundleplugin.BundlePlugin.execute(BundlePlugin.java:295)
    ... 23 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.core
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this problem? thanks

Comment: what is the maven version and java version you used?

Comment: @lakshman : this is the version that i use
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_31"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_31-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.31-b07, mixed mode)

$ mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.0.5 (r01de14724cdef164cd33c7c8c2fe155faf9602da; 2013-02-19 20:51:28+0700)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven30/3.0.5/libexec
Java version: 1.8.0_31, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.11.3", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issues with building java 8. You can build the v5.0.3 using java 7.